# Google Maps add layer

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm starting to develop an application that will have Google Maps.

I studied the help of Google Maps Api and I'm with doubt to add an overlay. The below is the correct way to do it:

Create maps

```
function initialize() {    
  var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
}
```

Add overload:

```
function add() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.646);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  }

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions); /* It is correct?

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      title:"Hello World!"
  });

  marker.setMap(map);
};
```

Is there a way to get the mapsOptions, or rather not recaregar the map completely, or is this how it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the `var`-keyword when creating the map in `initialize()` .
When you do so, the `map`-variable is global accessible and you may call `marker.setMap(map);` inside `add()` without creating a new Maps-instance.